# Send message to Facebook friends using graph api

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I am working on iOS app which will send message to FB friends. I auth the app and permission. But not able to send message to friends. Is there any way to send message friends. I see dropbox is sending message to friends.
Need help....

Answer (score 5):

Facebook messages are a channel for person-to-person communication, and not for apps to send messages, or encourage people to spam their friends. In general, games on Facebook.com should use requests when communicating in game status (its your turn), inviting people to use an application, or sending messages to multiple people. You should offer the Send Dialog in situations when someone might otherwise send an email.

Please refer this documentation :

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/

**UPDATE:**

And for your Dropbox concern...I think they are sending an mail to the particular user with their facebook email address (eg.username@facebook.com)

You can see this email address in your facebook General Account Settings.
and you can see this note below it which says:

"Your Facebook email is based on your public username. Email sent to this address goes to Facebook Messages."

and you can send attachments along with it as well....!!

Comment: But dropbox app is sending message to friends. I have installed dropbox on my iPod and its sending to message to friends and message shows on receiver end.

Comment: NSMutableDictionary *param;
        params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                  @"www.google.com", @"redirect_uri",
                  @"text", @"link",
                  @"my id as abcd.pqr.5", @"to",
                  APP_ID,@"app_id",
                  nil];
        
        [FBWebDialogs presentDialogModallyWithSession:nil dialog:@"mayank" parameters:param handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
                                                          
                                                          }}];

Comment: I know that it will send as message but in dropbox when u check facebook account you will see it as message not an email. It also shows a mail icon and expand tab to expand that message. In dropbox case its not happening. I don't know how to add image here otherwise i will show you. And one thing more if they are sending mail then it should open mail composer to send mail. iOS can not send mail in background.

Comment: just try and send an email with your registered facebook email id to one of your facebook friends' facebook email(username@facebook.com) and see what happens it will go right into their inbox messages and also try sending an attachment as well.....I know  iOS does not support mail in background..but you can achieve this with some backend server side mailing client...

Comment: Also email is not going through mail servers on @facebook.com. Can anyone help me please????

Comment: Mine is working perfectly fine. And let me see your code if you need any help.